# Image not being displayed on first function call - HTML5/Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html, google-chrome, canvas

The following code should display an image in a grid when I click the button. The issue is I have to click the button twice in order to see the images. I get the log output on both function calls, even when the images don't show up. What's going on?

EDIT: I've found out that the problem only occurs when chrome developer tools is open, so it's not a javascript problem.

EDIT2: In addition to the accepted answer, this link helped me: [Javascript Canvas Element - Array Of Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360392/javascript-canvas-element-array-of-images)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas Test</title>

        <script>
            function init() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                images = new Array();
            }

            function drawImage() {
                for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                        var index = i*12 + j;
                        images[index] = new Image();
                        images[index].src = 'image.jpg';
                        images[index].onload = function(image, index, i, j) {
                            console.log(index);
                            context.drawImage(image, i * 20, j * 20, 20, 20);
                            console.log("Loading image: " + image.src);
                        } (images[index], index, i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px" style="border: solid;"></canvas>
        <button onclick="drawImage();">Display Image</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code works. But sometimes the picture is not loaded and you will have to click the button twice.

[Try it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/W5cBn/3/)

---

2 problems:

- First,

```
function(image, index, i, j) {
    console.log(index);
    context.drawImage(image, i * 20, j * 20, 20, 20);
    console.log("Loading image: " + image.src);
}(images[index], index, i, j);
```

This will fire right way, because `()` at the end means to run it. That's why you have to click it twice.

- Second, `src` should come last. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Creating_an_image_from_scratch)) (but actually it doesn't matter)

To fix it, you have to make the function so that it won't run right away. Also because it is inside a loop and it uses scoped variables, it needs extra care. See code in demo.

[**>FIXED DEMO!<**](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/W5cBn/4/)

Comment: Yes, and that's what I got when I ran it on my code. But I don't understand why your change makes a difference.

Comment: @gsingh2011 - Okay, after playing with it, I found out that your code is actually working... (I didn't change anything except the picture in the demo)

Comment: You're right. And I found the issue. My problem only occurs when chrome developer tools is open. When it's closed it works fine. Strange...

Comment: When I test it after cache is cleared, the problem reappeared. (Developer tools is closed)

Comment: You're right again. I just remembered I had set my developer tools to disable caching. But I don't see how caching could cause this problem... The images would probably load slower, but they should at least show up.

Comment: First, You are doing this: `function(){}()`, which will fire the function right away. Second, [`src` should be set at the end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Creating_an_image_from_scratch). (after `onload`)